# Watershed scale water quality indices

Tags: models, water, watershed

I understand [water quality indices](http://www.mae.gov.nl.ca/waterres/quality/drinkingwater/dwqi.html) play a fundamental role in modelling water quality as they integrate multiple water quality parameters to bring about a single dimensionless digit that represents the overall quality of water corresponding to a textual rating.

However, the uses of water differ and the indices are usually calculated separately. I was wondering if there is a method for determining the water quality index on a watershed basis where multiple uses of water (ecosystem, drinking, irrigation etc) are integrated.